# Getting URL parameters on Wix using Safari and Mac

Tags: javascript, safari, velo

Code below. Will give me URL parameter on Mozilla, Edge, Chrome, any browser but Safari and Mac. On Safari it returns "undefined". http://example.com?id=123

How to make this code work on Safari? Wix code.

import wixLocation from 'wix-location';
import { fetch } from 'wix-fetch';

$w.onReady(function () {

```
let query = wixLocation.query['id'];
let id = decodeURIComponent(query); //decode uri encoded values in readable format
//console.log(id); //this is your id
```

I tried getting URL parameter but can't.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/979995/6133426) help?

Comment: No because Wix has its own scripting language

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the URL you're testing against? Also, this may or may not be the cause of your problems, but I see from your code that you're never closing the `$w.onReady(function() {` - there are no closing `}` (for the anonymous function) and `)` for the `onReady` event handler.